# Ubuntu booting to black screen

Tags: boot

“Trace 4 Ibuypower gaming pc”
Cpu: Amd Ryzen 5 3600
Gpu: Amd GX 5500
8 gb of ram

I am a total linux newbie and I installed fedora on my main yesterday. Fedora started black screening so I decided to use ubuntu. Ubuntu blacked screened too so I went on the forums. I went to this form: https://www.reddit.com/r/linuxquestions/comments/a4bt3j/vgacon_disables_amdgpu_kernel_modesetting/
I tried to do the booting with "amdgpu.dc=0" fix but that didn’t help. When I boot ubuntu to safe mode it lets me boot but still gives me the error in the forum. Im able to boot to tails in troubleshooting mode but not in normal mode too. Detailed help is appreciated, Im also not sure if I booted to “amdgpu.dc=0” correctly. Not sure if it helps but the last thing I see on ubuntu before the screen blacks is the operating system writing/accessing a “journal”.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [My computer boots to a black screen, what options do I have to fix it?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/162075/my-computer-boots-to-a-black-screen-what-options-do-i-have-to-fix-it)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So there was something wrong with my graphics card. Works now! I'm really not sure what happens but it seems like I leave my computer alone for a few days and it fixes it's self. My system seems to work strangely though, a few days ago I installed windows on a portion. It seems that whenever I use windows I get consistent black screens.